# how to send by directline, the ID of my QA environment?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm using directline to test my chatBot, I need to direct the tests to the QA environment, which has an id. how do i send this by directline?

Thanks

Comment: You say you are testing using DL. Does that mean you are using BotFramework-WebChat or sending via Postman or something else? Can you provide details on this and anything else you have tried?

Comment: I'm using by postman and I created a directline object with the directlineJS package. I would like to send tests by sending several questions to the bot, through directline. for that I need to direct to the QA environment that is identified by a secret. how to do this by postman collection and directline object?

Comment: Hi @StevenKanberg , sorry for the inconvenience.  some help?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I think there is some confusion about the role DirctLineJS plays and how you communicate to your bot via Postman. DLJS, which includes a set of APIs, is meant to be used for sending and receiving data between a client and a bot. DLJS connects to the Azure Bot Service Connector. The Connector routes all traffic between clients and their bots. BotFramework-WebChat, for instance, uses DLJS internally to do just this.

Comment: Postman can be used to test making DirectLine REST API calls if DLJS isn't a suitable option. There are a number of REST API endpoints that can be used to send and receive data from the bot. Like DLJS, the REST API communicates with a bot via the Connector. DLJS and the REST API are two different methods for doing the same thing. Communication between the two isn't intended.

Comment: All that being said, if you are using DLJS in some client, like a web page, you could create an endpoint for the site that you could POST to via Postman. When the endpoint is called, an event could be dispatched, or some function called, that would then include the data sent via Postman. The event/function would interact with DLJS to send that data to the bot.